# Code is working properly in local but not in server [WP]

Tags: php, wordpress

the following code is working properly in local but when i moved to server it showing error

**my code**

```
  $speaker_ID = get_post_custom_values('speaker')[0];
```

**error**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

is there any syntax error.? if how is it running in local?

**update**

this is because my server version is older,this syntax does not support

so icanged my code to

```
 $speaker_ID_array = get_post_custom_values("speaker");
                        $speaker_ID = $speaker_ID_array[0];
```

but now when i echo $speaker_ID like ,

```
echo $speaker_ID;
```

nothing is displayed.

Comment: That syntax was added in php 5.4, your server is probably older than that.

Comment: if there is any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax was added in php 5.4, your server must be running an older version.

As an alternative assign it to a variable first:

```
$speaker_ID_array = get_post_custom_values("speaker");
$speaker_ID = $speaker_ID_array[0];
```

Comment: i think this also not working befor that i can print echo  $speaker_ID but now i cant.

Comment: Does `get_post_custom_values("speaker")` return the value you expect?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(get_post_custom_values("speaker"))`?